# Facebook counter is 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have implemented the code, and the counter is always 0 or 1 if I like it but no more.
When I look in the API, there are many users who have liked or used the send button.

The code is on http://www.travelbag.co.uk.

Why is the code behaving in this way?

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=128983450473588&amp;xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:like href="http://www.travelbag.co.uk/?pid=facebook&sid=like" layout="button_count"
         width="60" show_faces="false" action="like" font=""></fb:like>
```

Comment: Please extract the relevant code and post it here. Having to dig through your site is no fun.

Comment: i have found there was a duplicate tag and adding in js script file, i have now removed this and see if it will work any better now

Comment: Make sure your site is passing Facebook debug: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.travelbag.co.uk%2F%3Fpid%3Dfacebook%26sid%3Dlike